# Result below input

Tags: javascript, html, css

how best can I put the result of each checkbox under the text?
Selecting the CheckBox displays the result that is in `value`, this result appears on the right side, as it would appear below?

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  var val = this.checked ? this.value : "";
  $(this).parent().next(".hello").text(val);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 15px;
}
    
.hello {
  width:380px;
  font: 11px Arial, sans-serif;
  color: green;
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>checkboxes</th>
    <th>Values</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name='cbox' value="red" class="theClass" />red
    </td>
    <td class="hello"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name='cbox2' value="green" class="theClass" />green
    </td>
    <td class="hello"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name='cbox3' value="blue" class="theClass" />blue
      <p></p>
    </td>
    <td class="hello"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Don't use a table? You're putting `val` into a table cell in the same table row as the checkbox. This is how tables display. Use different elements to get different behavior.

Comment: yes, I tried, but the only way to show the result is using the table

Comment: I'm sorry what? Are you saying that the only way to display things in 2019 is with a table? Oh man, we've all been doing it wrong for YEARS.

Comment: Nothing wrong with my "translator". I speak English. You said "the only way to show the result is using the table"

Comment: The "only way I could", if I could in other ways, wouldn't be publishing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need the second column, just one column, so the response appears Under the checkbox text. So you can style as you want...

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  var val = this.checked ? "<br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" +  this.value : "";
  $(this).next(".hello2").html(val);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 15px;
}
    
.hello2 {
  width:380px;
  font: 11px Arial, sans-serif;
  color: green;
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>checkboxes</th>
    <th>Values</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name='cbox1' value="red" class="theClass" />red<span class="hello2"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name='cbox2' value="green" class="theClass" />green<span class="hello2"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" name='cbox3' value="blue" class="theClass" />blue<span class="hello2"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: you should either remove the `<th>` for values or add an empty `<td>` because as it stands your markup is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You're question is not very clear. As such I really don't understand where you want the value to display. That being said, this shows the "value" under the "checkbox" as requested.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  var val = this.checked ? this.value : "";
  $(this).parent().next(".hello").text(val);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 15px;
}
    
.hello {
  width:380px;
  font: 11px Arial, sans-serif;
  color: green;
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>checkboxes</th>
    <th>Values</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name='cbox' value="red" class="theClass" />red</label>
      <div class="hello"></div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name='cbox2' value="green" class="theClass" />green</label>
      <div class="hello"></div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name='cbox3' value="blue" class="theClass" />blue</label>
      <div class="hello"></div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: yes thank you very much already solved with the friend of the post above but thank you very much for helping